# How to check whether date is in mm/DD/yyyy format or not in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

How do I check whether a date is in mm/DD/yyyy format or not in C#?

Answer (score 19):

Note: I'm assuming that you were asking whether a *string* is a valid date in "MM/dd/yyyy" format. A `DateTime` itself doesn't *have* a format, so you can't check that.

Use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) to try to parse it:

```
string text = "02/25/2008";
DateTime parsed;

bool valid = DateTime.TryParseExact(text, "MM/dd/yyyy",
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                    DateTimeStyles.None,
                                    out parsed);
```

Note that I've changed your format string to what I think you mean - I doubt that you really meant the first bit to be minutes, for example.

If you don't want the invariant culture, specify a different one :)

Comment: I want to create a method, where I can check that my date is having mm/DD/yyy format or not. If true then I will do some validation else leave.

Comment: @saurav2109: Sure, so use DateTime.TryParseExact as I suggested. I've now written up a code example for you.

Comment: Or regular expression can be used, though it's prone to errors. So DateTime.TryParseExact is a preferable way.

Comment: @Dmitry: A regular expression coping with leap years properly (excluding 1900, including 2400 etc) would be *awful* :)

Comment: +1 - the best way I know to do this as well. Just be aware that you can't be sure whether a user supplied value of `"01/02/2011"` is MM/dd/yyyy (January 2, 2011) or dd/MM/yyyy (February 1, 2011), since both will successfully be parsed. But that might very well be a minor issue, depending on the context (and I can't really see any way to deal with it, without knowing the date in advance).

Comment: @Jon: Yes, exactly! I've provided this as an option to those who love to build their own bicycles :)

Comment: @Jon: Thanks a lot for all your input. Is there any generic method to convert any type of format to dd-MM-YYYY format in C#. Cause if I use your method if will convert only dd/MM/yyyy format to dd-MM-yyyy.

Comment: DateTime convertedEE = DateTime.Parse(EEEffectiveDate); EEEffectiveDateFormated = convertedEE.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"); If I will use this way it will create a problem where I have date in dd/MM/yyyy format. Any generic way to do any kind of format to dd-MM-yyyy format.